# Join two arrays on same id

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables:

- table one with `visit_id, revenue`
- table two with `visit_id, array_products_visited` with an array of products visited on my website
- table three with `visit_id, array_bought` with an array of products bought on my website

When I join the everything, the products bought (table three) appear repeated by each and every products visited. How can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Edit: to help you understand what I mean

table one:

| visit_id |
| --- |
| 123456 |
| 123457 |

table two

| visit_id | product_visited_id | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 | name 1 |
|  | 2 | name 2 |
|  | 3 | name 3 |

table three

| visit_id | product_bought_id | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 | name 1 |
|  | 2 | name 2 |

this is what I'm currently getting:

| visit_id | product_visited_id | product_name | product_bought_id | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 | name 1 | 1 | name 1 |
|  | 2 | name 2 | 1 | name 1 |
|  | 3 | name 3 | 1 | name 1 |
|  | 1 | name 1 | 2 | name 2 |
|  | 2 | name 2 | 2 | name 2 |
|  | 3 | name 3 | 2 | name 2 |

and this is what I would like to get:

| visitID | product_visited_id | product_name | product_bought_id | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 | name 1 | 1 | name 1 |
|  | 2 | name 2 | 2 | name 2 |
|  | 3 | name 3 |  |  |

and my code looks somewhat like this:

```sql
SELECT
  visit_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
            product_visited_id,
            product_name)
           ) AS products_visited,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
            product_bought_id,
            product_name)
           ) AS products_bought,
  FROM table_one
  LEFT JOIN table_two USING(visit_id)
  LEFT JOIN table_three USING(visit_id)
  GROUP BY visit_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a WHERE clause that limits the rows, so you only see the ones where two.user_id=three.userid.

Comment: Hey Lionel, thanks. I've added an example for a better understading of my problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  visit_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
            product_visited_id,
            product_name)
           ) AS products_visited,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
            product_bought_id,
            product_name)
           ) AS products_bought,
 FROM (SELECT *
  FROM table_one
  LEFT JOIN table_two USING(visit_id)
  LEFT JOIN table_three USING(visit_id)
  GROUP BY visit_id)
```